# Powershell command to color string and replace within document

Tags: powershell, str-replace

I have never worked with PowerShell before, but we have a script at work that outputs the jobs which are running to a WordPad. The script already outputs the job name and "In Progress" for everything that is running. I would like to highlight green the words "In Progress". After I checked online and watched some tutorial, this is as far as I got:

```
$Txt_File = "C:\Users\..."
$Selection = "In Progress"

$Change = Get-Content $Txt_File

$Change | ForEach-Object {$_-replace "In Progress", $Selection} | Set-Content $Txt_File
```

I thought that a good option will be to define a string "In progress" which will be on a green background and by using `$_replace` find the exact words in my document and replace them with the string `$Selection`. This is where I got stuck... I have tried using `-Foregroudcolor`, `wdcolor`, `Font.color`, but every time I was getting an error. If you could help me or at least point me in a right direction.

Comment: you don't appear to be dealing with a `wordpad` file. instead, it looks like you are working with a plain text file ... and those are just that - _plain text_. powershell DOES NOT have any way to write directly to a `wordpad` file. ///// also, the `-ForegroundColor` stuff is ONLY for `Write-Host` [or `Write-Information` if you can figure out how] access to the display screen.

Comment: Do you mean a `.RTF` (_[Rich Text Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)_) file or a _plain text_ one?

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey and JosefZ,  the script outputs the result to a Wordpad. Please see below

`code omnistat -details | Out-File C:\Users\...omnistat.rtf`

Comment: you keep saying "to a wordpad" ... but never specify what wordpad format you are talking about. the _default_ wordpad format is RTF and it is a **_highly structured text file_**. if you want to create OR modify RTF files, you need to comply with that structure. powershell has no such native support. to powershell, files are binary, plain text, CSV, JSON, HTML, or XML. you can access others via dotnet code OR via external utils. ///// i cannot find any RTF module or code for letting PoSh work with RTF files. you appear to need to create your own ... sorry for that bad news.

Answer (score 0):

Let's reverse-engineer a quick-and-dirty solution, so you can see the RTF formatting first-hand.

For starters, here's the contents of a generic RTF file created in WordPad:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.18362}\viewkind4\uc1
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9 The quick\par
brown\par
In Progress\par
fox jumped\par
In Progress\par
over the\par
In Progress\par
lazy dog\par
}
```

Coloring the 'In Progress' lines with a green background color and white font color in WordPad produced this RTF:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green128\blue0;}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.18362}\viewkind4\uc1
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9 The quick\par
brown\par
\cf1\highlight2 In Progress\cf0\highlight0\par
fox jumped\par
\cf1\highlight2 In Progress\cf0\highlight0\par
over the\par
\cf1\highlight2 In Progress\cf0\highlight0\par
lazy dog\par
}
```

Thus, it appears you might want something similar to this:

```
$Rtf_File = 'C:\Users\...\Example.rtf'
$Selection = 'In Progress'
$Rtf_Replacement = "\cf1\highlight2 $Selection\cf0\highlight0"
$Insert2ndRow = '{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green128\blue0;}'

$rows = Get-Content -Path $Rtf_File
$rows[0],$Insert2ndRow,$rows[1..($rows.count-1)] | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $Selection, $Rtf_Replacement } | Set-Content -Path $Rtf_File
```

...which basically inserts a color definition row in the second line of the RTF, and replaces any occurrence of 'In Progress' with a colorized RTF version of it.

***Keep in mind, this quick and dirty solution really knows nothing about RTF structure, so it may potentially corrupt some pre-formatted RTF files.  Therefore, make backups of your files, and use at your own risk.***

Hope this helps, nonetheless.